# matplotlib.pyplot package is absent

Tags: matplotlib

I have downloaded matplotlib through terminal succesfully
.But when i try to import it , my idle is throwing up an error

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/matplotlib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package
```

What should i do.?

Comment: It looks like you have a python script named `matplotlib.py` in the same folder you want to run the import from. This is a rather unfortunate choice, because that is exactly the name from the library/module you want to import, so the import would try to import your `matplotlib.py`, rather than the module of the same name.